# Must I specify the jooq Result type?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Is there a way to not specify all the type arguments in the example below? I've tried using just "Record", but to no avail.

```
   Map<Integer,Result<Record6<Integer, String, Integer, String, String, Integer>>> records = db()
            .select(TRANSITIONS.TRANSITION_ID, TRANSITIONS.TYPE, POSES.POSE_ID, POSES.NAME, IMAGES.URL, IMAGES.SCORE.max())
            .from(TRANSITIONS
            .join(POSES).on(POSES.POSE_ID.equal(TRANSITIONS.TO_POSE_ID))
            .join(IMAGES).on(IMAGES.POSE_ID.equal(POSES.POSE_ID)))
            .where(TRANSITIONS.FROM_POSE_ID.equal(fromPoseId))
            .groupBy(TRANSITIONS.TRANSITION_ID, TRANSITIONS.TYPE, POSES.POSE_ID, POSES.NAME, IMAGES.URL)
            .fetchGroups(TRANSITIONS.TRANSITION_ID);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way Java generics work, you cannot get a

```java
Map<Integer, Result<?>> // or
Map<Integer, Result<Record>>
```

From the [`fetchGroups()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchGroups%28org.jooq.Field%29) method, given its signature:

```java
<K> Map<K, Result<R>> fetchGroups(Field<K> key)
```

You can work around this issue, however, by tweaking the `<R>` type of your `ResultQuery`, either by unsafe casting, or by making the whole select less typesafe as such:

```java
db().select(new Field[] { 
    TRANSITIONS.TRANSITION_ID, 
    TRANSITIONS.TYPE, 
    POSES.POSE_ID, 
    POSES.NAME, 
    IMAGES.URL, 
    IMAGES.SCORE.max() 
}).from(...)
```

Or using this trick:

```java
db().select(...) // "Typesafe" select clause
    .select()    // Additional select clause removing typesafety
```